# Hide some series in legend on an embedded combo chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to hide some series legend on a EmbeddedComboChartBuilder. For this I'm using the following code and data:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX...');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

var chartTable1Range = sheet.getRange("J2:M20");

var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)  
  .setOption('legend', {position: 'bottom', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 12}})
  .setOption('hAxis', {
      title: 'X',
      format: '#,##'
    })
    .setOption('vAxes', {0: {
      title: 'Y', format: '#,##'
    }})
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
    .addRange(chartTable1Range)
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setOption('series', {
    0: {
      type: 'bars', 
      color: 'red',
      labelInLegend: '0'
    },
    1: {
      type: 'bars', 
      color: 'blue',      
      visibleInLegend: false
    },      
    2: {
      type: 'line', 
      color: 'green',
      labelInLegend: '2'
    }
  })
  .build();

sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

The data used in this exemple are:

```
Obs1    0.432   0.4368989894    0.235
Obs2    0.174   0.3664337833    0.235
Obs3    0.051   0.2241215124    0.235
Obs4    0.006   0.6898471576    0.235
Obs5    0.001   0.2739759422    0.235
Obs6    0.013   0.1598647037    0.235
Obs7    0.024   0.9352614542    0.235
Obs8    0.029   0.8001979514    0.235
Obs9    0.034   0.2609976374    0.235
Obs10   0.034   0.4658054115    0.235
Obs11   0.028   0.07040885359   0.235
Obs12   0.024   0.904232147     0.235
Obs13   0.012   0.08875849971   0.235
Obs14   0.008   0.7557879194    0.235
Obs15   0       0.3110038624    0.235
Obs16   0.003   0.004167741537  0.235
Obs17   0.007   0.5128489082    0.235
Obs18   0.194   0.7116776294    0.235
Obs19   0.629   0.4534584462    0.235
```

It seems that the option **visibleInLegend** has no effect as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

The blue square in the legend should not be displayed because the option visibleInLegend is set to false for this serie.

Any ideas why this option does not work !

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet with the data (real or fake, don't share personal data) to reproduce it?

Comment: I have update my problem description with the data. @Kessy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a similar issue on Google Issue Tracker.

You can go there and star the issue to be updated on it:

[Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179999768)